# C++ How to open .docx files in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, docx

How can I open .docx files in MFC?
Because when I open a .docx file it puts "PK" to the editor. (This is at every .docx file I have opened)

Comment: docx is not a text file format. Its a compressed XML file. You should see the same behavior if you read it in notepad

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161295/reading-docx-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161295/reading-docx-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading .docx in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161295/reading-docx-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.docx files are .zip files with a different extension. The content of the zip is essentially a directory structure containing various XML files.

To open a .docx in a text editor would basically require unzipping the file to a directory then opening each XML file in your editor.

The actual format of .docx files can be found online.